# StraceNTの不可解なエラー

Tags: c#, windows, debugging

Windows 10 Pro 21H2 日本語版の環境で [StraceNT](https://github.com/ipankajg/stracent) というツールについて調べています。

不可解なエラーに遭遇したのですが解決方法がわかりませんでしたのでアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか。

#### 手順

簡単なトレース対象のプログラムとして次の内容のファイル hello.cs を作る

```cs
using System;
class Hello
{
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("hello, world");
    }
}
```

OS同梱のC#コンパイラでコンパイルして実行ファイル hello.exe を作り、動作確認する

```
PS C:\tmp> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe .\hello.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.4084.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

PS C:\tmp> .\hello.exe
hello, world
```

stracent.exe でトレースを実行する

```
PS C:\tmp> .\stracent.exe .\hello.exe

System Call Tracer for Windows XP - Windows 10. (Version: 0.9.3.0)
Copyright (c): Pankaj Garg <pankaj@intellectualheaven.com>.       
All rights reserved.

Tracing command: [".\hello.exe"]

Error: ?????????????????
```

#### 質問

なぜ hello.exe のトレースができないのでしょうか。

`stracent.exe notepad` では正しく notepad.exe のトレースができました。

`stracent.exe C:\Windows\notepad.exe` では同じエラーによりトレースできませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのプロジェクトの info.txt の Supported platforms に 32bit OS または 64bit OS でも wow64 の中で動作する 32bit process だけトレース出来ると記述されています。
[Supported platforms: - stracent/hlp/info.txt](https://github.com/ipankajg/stracent/blob/master/hlp/info.txt#L55)

> Windows 2000
> Windows XP (32-bit)
> Windows 2003 (32-bit)
> Windows XP (64-bit) - For tracing 32bit process *only* running inside wow64
> Windows 2003 (64-bit) - For tracing 32bit process *only* running inside wow64

つまり正常に動作する、パスを指定しない`stracent.exe notepad`だと、32bitアプリの`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe`が起動していると思われます。

C#のHello.exeは特に何も指定しなければ AnyCPU モードで作成され、64bit OSでは64bitモードで動作するのでしょう。

パスを指定した`stracent.exe C:\Windows\notepad.exe`では、指定された`C:\Windows\notepad.exe`は64bitモードで動作するプログラムと言うことなのでしょう。

そうして64bitアプリのトレースは出来ないのでエラーになっていると思われます。文字化けはそういう未対応であることの副産物でしょうか。

C#のHello.exeを32bitアプリに特化した形でビルドするオプションがあれば、それを指定して試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: なるほど、StraceNTはx86専用のツールだったんですね。 notepadの挙動など、いろいろと合点がいきました。[Issue](https://github.com/ipankajg/stracent/issues/2) もありましたね…。
実際にトレースしたいのはx64のアプリなので、残念ながらこのツールを使うことはなさそうです。

Comment: この辺のツールが使えるかもしれませんね。[プロセス モニター v3.87](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), [SpyStudio](https://www.nektra.com/products/spystudio-api-monitor/), [Detours を使って API の実行履歴やその戻り値を確認](https://troushoo.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-406.html), [microsoft/Detours](https://github.com/Microsoft/Detours/), [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), [WinAPIOverride](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。procmon はすでに使用しておりますがかゆいところに手が届かぬ感じでした。
なお文字化けについては別の質問を作りましたので、よろしければ回答をお願いします: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/86393/9873