# Windows 版の Qt Creator で日本語を qDebug で出力すると文字化けする

Tags: c++, windows, qt, 文字化け, qt-creator

Windows上のQt(C++)で以下の様なコードで日本語を含む文字列をデバッグ出力すると
アプリケーション出力ペインに文字化けして出力されてしまいます。

```
qDebug << "あいうえお" << number ;
```

Releaseビルドの時は文字化けしないで上手く行くのですが、Debugビルド時に出力を日本語で確認したいのですが何か方法は無いでしょうか。
--- 以下追記です
Qt Creator 7.0.2
プロジェクトは
Qt 5.9.9 MinGW 32bit
Qt 6.2.2 MinGW 64bit
です

オプションはプロジェクトを作成したときのまま変更していません
デバッグビルドでステップ実行(F5)　:文字化けする
デバッグビルドで実行(CTRL+R)　　　:文字化けしない
リリースビルドでステップ実行(F5)　:文字化けする
リリースビルドで実行(CTRL+R)　　　:文字化けしない

試したコードは

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << "デバッグ";
}
```

Comment: コンパイラは何を使っているか、DebugとReleaseで指定しているオプションとその違いは何か、といったことを確認して追記してみてください。

Comment: Qt Creatorは6.0.2
コンパイラは5.9.9MinGW32bitと5.14.2MinGW64bitです。
debugとreleaseで異なっているのはプロジェクトのビルド設定くらいですが、
QML debugging and profilingが「enable」か「Leave at Default」が違うくらいで、試しに変更してみても変わりませんでした。
Debugビルド時とReleaseビルド時にqDebugの出力文字コードが変わってしまう設定は探してみたのですが、見当たらなかったです

Comment: コメントではイマイチ見難いので記事に追記してください。それからあまりにも長大というのでなければ、それらの内容の全てを記述した方が他の人が調べる際に必要な情報の有無をやり取りしなくて済むので手っ取り早いと思われます。

Comment: ちなみにこんな記事 [StraceNTの不可解なエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/86377/26370) からの類推で、対象プログラムとデバッガ等のツールの32/64bit指定が合っていないとかありませんか？

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Qt5で日本語文字列を扱おうとすると文字化けするので、その対処方法 \[Qt\]](https://nprogram.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/10/071536), [Qt とソースファイルの文字コード](https://qt-labs.jp/2013/08/qt-and-source-and-codecs.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のようなコードでステップ実行(F5)と通常の実行(CTRL+R)を試したところ、
F5の時は全て文字化け
CTRL+Rの時はfromLocal8Bitで文字化けになりました
Linux上だとそもそも、問題なくqDebugは出力できるのですが
不便ではあるのですが、あくまでデバッグ出力での話なのでとりあえず締めてしまいます

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << "日本語";

    QString temp1 = QString::fromLocal8Bit("日本語");
    QString temp2 = QString::fromUtf8("日本語");
    QString temp3 = QString::fromStdString("日本語");
    QString temp4 = QString::fromLatin1("日本語");

    qDebug() << "fromLocal8Bit:" << temp1;
    qDebug() << "fromUtf8:" << temp2;
    qDebug() << "fromStdString:" << temp3;
    qDebug() << "fromLatin1:" << temp4;
}
```

F5で実行(ステップ実行)

```
���{��
fromLocal8Bit: "日本��"
fromUtf8: "���{��"
fromStdString: "���{��"
fromLatin1: "a\u0097\a\u009C��ea\u009E"
```

CTRL+Rで実行

```
日本語
fromLocal8Bit: "譌･譛ｬ隱"
fromUtf8: "日本語"
fromStdString: "日本語"
fromLatin1: "a\u0097\a\u009C￢ea\u009E"
```